# Accessing StackExchange inbox

Tags: support, feature-request

Can I access my StackExchange mailbox in a different way than the pop up that appears when I click the 'Stack **Exchange**' button at the top left?
The popup immediately pops away on my tablet, so I can never read my messages. :-(

This is what it looks like on my PC:
[image]

Comment: details of your tablet setup?

Comment: Android 4.1.1 on asus transformer prime TF201. Browser has the much inspiring name "Browser" and comes with version 4.1.1-WW_epad-10.4.2.15

Comment: browser version continued: -20120917

Comment: The page itself exists on SE: http://stackexchange.com/users/<someNumber>/<username>?tab=inbox It is on the stack exchange network profile page. Guess that answers the question, wish though it wasn't so well hidden.

Comment: I haven't tried any of the solutions there, but you might find [Is there a RSS to the 'Stack Exchange Inbox'? How about to Activity?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85897/138432) useful.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the answers at [Is there a RSS to the 'Stack Exchange Inbox'? How about to Activity?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85897/138432), if you don't want to use a third party service and only want the responses or activity feed for a single Stack Exchange site, you could use some variant of:

- https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/8627/responses
- https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/8627
- https://electronics.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/8627/responses
- https://electronics.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/8627

Alas I can't find an equivalent for Stack Exchange.

I have also posted the question [What other hidden or inobvious RSS feeds are available on stackexchange and stack exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151519/138432) over on stackoverflow meta, to see if there are any other feeds available.